# How to properly get Access Token from logged in Google Sign In (client-side only app)?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-javascript-client

I am using Google Sign-In button to let user logging in with their Google Account:

```
    gapi.signin2.render("container-btn-google-login", {
        scope: "email profile",
        onsuccess: (user) => {
            let token = user.getAuthResponse();
            setToken(token);

            // How can I get the Access Token here
            // that should be the same as user.Zi.access_token?

            resolve(token);
        },
    });
```

I am going to call other Google APIs and do not want to use their Javascript library (I am going to use `fetch` to call their REST APIs).

However, when I put `Authorization: token.id_token` as Header, the request is rejected. If I manually put a value that I can see from the Console (`user.Zi.access_token`), it works.

How can I extract the `access_token` from Google API Javascript SDK? Using something cryptic and undocumented like `Zi` does not seem safe to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have found the [relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#googleusergetauthresponseincludeauthorizationdata) here. We can use `user.getAuthResponse(true)` to get the Auth Response with the access token and possibly other useful information:

The parameter is `includeAuthorizationData`:

> Optional: A boolean that specifies whether to always return an access
>   token and scopes. By default, the access token and requested scopes
>   are not returned when fetch_basic_profile is true (the default value)
>   and no additional scopes are requested.

Example working code from my question:

```
let token = user.getAuthResponse(true);
console.log(token.access_token)
```